# Sencha Touch - can't get values from other function

Tags: javascript, extjs, geolocation, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 functions and would like to call one function from another and get 2 values.

```
renderMap: function(){
    // here I need to call getCurrentLocation function and get 2 values - lat and lng from it.
    console.log(lat, lng);
},

getCurrentLocation: function() {
    var me = this,
        lat,
        lng;

    Ext.device.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({     
        success: function(position) {
            me.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            me.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        }
    });
},
```

Please advise on how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return object from getCurrentLocation, for example:

```
return {lat:xxxx, lng:yyyy};
```

Comment: There is one more thing to the point. The device call is asynchronous what means that `getCurrentLocation` does not return the location data. It only initializes the device request and returns immediately.

After the location data is known function `success` is called so you could call `renderMap` from it.

Answer (score 2):

`me` doesn't exist anymore when you call `Ext.device.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

You are in a different context or scope by then, `Ext.device.Geolocation` class knows nothing about `me` variable.

At the beginning of your method  this refered to your controller, but then you are invoking `getCurrentPosition` method of `Ext.device.Geolocation` class, since you are not passing any parameters to the method `me` should be `undefined`.

It think you can solve this with Ext.bind

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-bind

Also look for call and apply in JavaScript :)

Best regards @code4jhon